# For almost every $x$ $\forall\varepsilon>0:\ |f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon\ \Rightarrow\ f=g$ almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, lebesgue-measure

Seems intuitive, but what would be the rigorous proof?

Comment: In general, if $\forall \epsilon >0, |a|<\epsilon$ then $a=0$. So it just follows.

Comment: It's a little harder to show if $\forall \epsilon>0(\text {for almost all $x$}...)$ because then it doesn't just follow from simple definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am not mistaken but isn't that easier by contradiction?

The negation of $f=g$ a.e. is "there exists a set $A$ whose measure is different from $0$ and on which $f\neq g$".

Suppose that there exists a set $A$, whose measure is not zero, and such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for any $x\in A$ (i.e. $f=g\text{ (a.e.)}$ is false) . Then, for any $x_{0}\in A$, you have $f(x_{0})-g(x_{0})\neq 0$. Hence, taking $\epsilon=\tfrac{1}{2}\vert f(x_{0})-g(x_{0})\vert$ and you get a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\forall\varepsilon>0\left|f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right|<\varepsilon\iff f\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$$

Comment: is that a definition?

Comment: No, it is not a definition. Can you prove it? If so then you can also prove that  the answer to the question in the title is "yes".

Comment: Oh I see... proof by contradiction. I did not think of that

Comment: @Tom83B this's exactly the Archimede property of the real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Let $D$ be the set such that $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in D$. What can be said about the value of $f(x)-g(x)$ for $x\in D$?

Comment: well $-\varepsilon<f(x)-g(x)<\varepsilon$

Comment: ...for every value of $\varepsilon$, no matter how small.

Comment: of course, I get that, but I somehow think that just 'stating so' is not rigorous enough.

Comment: If you have a number $a$ so that $-\varepsilon<a<\varepsilon$ for every positive value of $\varepsilon$, the only possible conclusion is that $a=0$. This is perfectly rigorous as it follows immediately from the ordering axioms of the real numbers.

Comment: Well as mentioned above - I think the rigorous way is proof by contradiction